# Problemas para cambiar de activity principal [Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

tengo problemas con indicarle al programa que quiero que mi activity 2 sea la principal, probé cambiando en manifest las lineas de  dentro de la  que queria colocar de principal y en el menu `Launch Options` coloque `Specified activity`, pero ninguna de las dos me funcionó, el programa instala bien en el celular pero cuando la abro se cierra. este es mi manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test4">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código del encabezado del Layout que corresponde a la segunda actividad `Main2Activity` porque revisando lo que colocas debería cambiarte el activity de la aplicación.

Comment: La configuración que realizas es correcta, en este caso el error se encuentra en otra parte, seguramente dentro de Main2Activity, es muy importante revises el LogCat y agregues el error que se registra ahí

Comment: Revisando el LogCat en la sección de errores me di cuenta que había una linea que tenia un hipervinculo a "Main2Activity" hacia una linea especifica y especificaba que la variable que estaba siendo creada en esa linea no podía ser nula, por lo que solucione ese caso y funciono. Muchas gracias Roberto y Jorgesys, sus comentarios me ayudaron un montón porque no sabia donde buscar.